# CMD read file via for in

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have a very simple batch script that reads a txt file and echo's it's content. The script is:

```
@echo off
set WORK_BASE_DIR=%~dp0
set BUILD_TXT=%WORK_BASE_DIR%Build.txt
echo %BUILD_TXT%

set PRODUCT_BUILD=0.0

for /F %%i in ("%BUILD_TXT%") do set PRODUCT_BUILD=%%i
echo %PRODUCT_BUILD%
```

The output of this script is:

```
D:\Test Dir\Project1\Build.txt    \\Correct
D:\Test                           \\Incorrect
```

As you can see, the `PRODUCT_BUILD` is set to the path of the file and not the content of the file. The build.txt file is in the same directory and it contains just one line: `1.0.0000`

If I remove the `""` from the `for` statement, it says `build.txt` file not found, which is expected as the file path contains spaces.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to the help of [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) (type `for /?` into a command prompt window), quotation marks denote a literal string, unless you specify the `usebackq` option:

```cmd
for /F "usebackq" %%i in ("%BUILD_TXT%") do set "PRODUCT_BUILD=%%i"
```

In addition, let me recommend to use the quoted `set` syntax as shown above, which avoids problems with special characters and prevents invisible unintended trailing spaces to become part of the assigned value. Note that this only works if [command extensions](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) are enabled, but this is the default in every modern Windows version (based on Windows NT) anyway.